# Recursive list of items in PHP, unknown depth and nodes

Tags: php, recursion, tree

gurus! 
First of all, I've spent half a day googlin'n'stackoverflowing but couldn't find a solution. This is my first time working with recursions. Hope someone can help.

I have a MySQL table, this is kind of referal system:

```
Table 'users'

ID   SPONSORID
---------
1    2         
2    1         
3    1         
4    1         
...  ...
```

There are several things to keep in mind:

1. Users 1 and 2 are sponsors/referals of each other.
2. Each user can have unlimited number of referals.
3. Each user's referal becomes a sponsor as well and can also have unlimited number of referals
4. Depth is unlimited.

The task is to recursively build a tree of a single "team", like:

```
User 1
    User 2
        User 1
        User 5
             ...
                 ....
    User 3
        User 295
             User 356
                 ....
    User 4
```

and so on...

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$team = Array();
function build_team( $userID, $team ){
    if ( !in_array($userID, $team ) :
        // get 1st level of referals
        // returns associative array ('id', 'login', 'sponsorid')
        $referals = get_user_referals( $userID );
        for ( $i=0; $i<count($referals); $i++ ) :
            $team[] = $referals[$i];
            build_team( $referals[$i]['id'] );
        endfor;
    endif;
}
```

And also tried putting that IF inside the FOR block, but it still goes in infinite loop. As I understand I need a condition to quit recursion when there's no depth level but I can't understand how to calculate/determine it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give an example of a few records from the database and the expected tree that should result?  I don't quite understand what you are trying to build, so I can't help you.  I love recursive problems, though!

Comment: @LeviMorrison, thanks. Here's a dump of MySQL table (only part of it): https://gist.github.com/df852eabe787d716af08

Comment: Could you build the expected tree by hand for the first 20 results in that gist? That way we can see what you want.  Right now it's difficult to recommend solutions when I'm not really sure what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Here's updated SQL (removed unnecessary columns and limited to 50 rows) https://gist.github.com/df852eabe787d716af08 and expected result examples: https://gist.github.com/b597416d33ae1eb790a6

Answer (score 2):

Keep users ids, whom are already "built", somewhere. As you said yourself - "Users 1 and 2 are sponsors/referals of each other.", so there is your infinite loop.

Something like

```
if (!in_array($userId, $already_looped_users){

  //continue loop...

}
```

Adding some code:

```
$team = Array();
function build_team( $userID, $team ){
     if ( !in_array($userID, $team ) :
        // get 1st level of referals
        // returns associative array ('id', 'login', 'sponsorid')
        $referals = get_user_referals( $userID );
        if (count($referals) > 0){ //added this line
          for ( $i=0; $i<count($referals); $i++ ) :
              $team[] = $referals[$i];
              $team[$referals[$i] = build_team( $referals[$i]['id'], $team ); // i've edited this line
          endfor;
          return $team; 
        }
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @egis. I've edited the code and tried to add this check but it still fails. Please, check the edited code above.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Changed one line of our code and added a `return` statement (you weren't returining built teams from function).

Comment: Now it went off the infinite loop, thanks. But it builds only first level and shows `Warning: Illegal offset type` for this line: `$team[$curr][] = build_team( $referals[$i]['id'], $team )`. Trying to find the bug. Thanks for help!

Comment: I've edited my code, added `if` statement after referrals fetching.